# Cannot access properties of Sheet object in Powershell OpenXML

Tags: powershell, openxml-sdk

I have this powershell script which write the type of the last worksheet from an `xlsm` document :

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll"
$Document = $null
$Document = [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument]::Open("C:\Users\200207121\Documents\Sandbox\FastPrep_S7_Modified_AVELIA_LZB.xlsm", $false)
$Sheets = $Document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets
$LastSheet = $Sheets.LastChild
Write-Host $LastSheet.GetType()
$Document.Close()
```

This outputs

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet
```

I need to know for sure that `$LastSheet` is an object of type [Sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheet?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=openxml-2.8.1), which must have all the properties listed in the documentation.

However, I can't access most of the properties specified in the official documentation

```
Write-Host "Type is $($LastSheet.GetType())"
Write-Host "State is $($LastSheet.State)"
Write-Host "state is $($LastSheet.state)"
```

This outputs

```
Type is DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet
State is
state is
```

Why am I unable to access those properties ? Am I using the wrong library ? Is the doc outdated ? Is my syntax wrong ?

Edit : I have tried downloading the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml) of the package, and import it instead. This produces the exact same behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `State` is null when the sheet is visible (default).

This makes sense when looking at the underlying tag `<x:sheets>` :

```
<x:sheet name="Sheet 1" sheetId="155" r:id="rId3"/>
<x:sheet name="Sheet 2" sheetId="140" state="veryHidden" r:id="rId4"/>
<x:sheet name="Sheet 3" sheetId="130" state="veryHidden" r:id="rId5"/>
```

The `state`attribute is only specified for hidden/veryHidden sheets. If I update my powershell code to lookup a sheet that is actually hidden, I get the appropriate behaviour.

In my opinion, the doc is totally misleading regarding this property :

> state (Visible State) Specifies the visible state of this sheet.
>
> The default value for this attribute is "visible."
>
> The possible values for this attribute are defined by the
> ST_SheetState simple type (§18.18.68).

The default value is **NOT** 'visible'. It is **null**.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. It does seem you have an instance, and you could explore the properties, methods, and events of that instance using Get-Member:

Try:

```
$lastSheet | Get-Member # to see what the object can do
```

2. You might be able to sidestep this entirely by using the excellent module [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: I already thought of that, but for some reason, `$LastSheet | Get-Member` throws _Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet._. I had to use `-InputObject` instead of piping. This led me to an understanding of the SDK which I posted as an answer below.